# What does this mean: 操

Tags: mandarin

One of my chinese friends always writes this on my notebook at University and laughs.

I don't seem to understand what's so funny about it. any explanation would be fantastic.

Comment: When pronounced cao4, it means 'fuck'. This is a slang.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it looks like a vulgar word was posted as a joke.

Comment: @DonKirkby I would've closed it as offtopic/general reference because no effort's shown in looking the word up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"操" means "fuck".

It's usage in Chinese is close to fuck in English.

ps:As a Chinese I can understand him , at hometown you rarely have any chance to say those bad language whenever and wherever you want in public because everyone knows what you are saying.

Answer (score 1):

It has multiple meanings. The relevant one here is "fuck".

Some other meanings of the character:

1. To hold, to grip
2. To control
3. To train
4. To speak in a specified language or accent

Answer (score 1):

One of the meanings of 操 is fuck.

In Chinese, you can say "fuck your relatives (e.g. father, mother, grandma etc)"

**Common use:**

fuck your

1. mum 操你妈;
2. grandma 操你奶奶.